# How to change Windows line-ending to Unix version

Tags: command-line, bash

We have 10 PC with some version of Ubuntu and only remote access. While doing some upgrades to custom software I did not notice that the line endings in some scripts were Windows version (CR+LF) and not the Unix version (LF). So now when I want to launch the script it gives an error:

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/portsee: /usr/bin/python^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to change all line endings in a script from terminal. The thing is that I can not install any new software to this group of PC-s.

Comment: Use the `sed` command from the duplicate's accepted answer.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

#### Option 1: `dos2unix`

You can use the program `dos2unix`, which is specifically designed for this:

```
dos2unix file.txt
```

will replace all CR from all lines, in place operation.

To save the output in a different file:

```
dos2unix -n file.txt output.txt
```

You might need to install it first by:

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
```

#### Option 2: `sed`

Or you can use `sed` to replace all CR (`\r`) from line endings:

```
sed -i.bak 's/\r$//' file.txt
```

With option `-i`, the file will be edited in-place, and the original file will be backed up as `file.txt.bak`.

Comment: `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` are present in cygwin as well

Comment: [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/279818/267627) shows applying `dos2unix` recursively. Useful when moving a git repo from windows to ubuntu.

Comment: `sed` worked for me but  had to supply the global flag as in: ```sed -i.bak 's/\r$//g' file.txt```

Comment: If anyone else gets an `illegal byte sequence` error when using the `sed` command, just add this one the same line before the sed command: `LC_ALL=C sed ...`

Comment: You can do the same thing with perl where you can update multiple files at once:

`perl -pi.bak -e 's/\r$//' manyFiles.* `

For each file, there will be a .bak file with the original contents.

Answer (score 6):

The `sed` solution is not portable to all platforms. It didn't work for me on macOS unless I did `brew install gsed` and used `gsed 's/\r$//'`.

For a solution that works in most places without installing anything, I use

```
tr -d '\r'
```

To edit a file in-place, I produce the new data in a subshell before erasing and overwriting the original file:

```
echo "$(tr -d '\r' < file)" > file
```

Comment: [Sponge from moreutils](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/moreutils/sponge.1.en.html) is a nice utility for reading and writing in the same line as well: `tr -d '\r' <file | sponge file`. It writes to memory until STDOUT finishes, then writes the contents to the file.

Comment: Useful if you have `sponge` installed, but it's not installed by default on macOS.