# Running Script made in Visual Studio Code (on windows) on WSL Ubuntu returns "line 2: $'\r': command not found"

Tags: bash, scripts, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-code

When I try to run a script made with Visual Studio Code on Windows in my Ubuntu WSL installation, I get the error:

```
line 2: $'\r': command not found
```

I ran into the question below:

[How do I fix "$'\r': command not found" errors running Bash scripts in WSL?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966488/how-do-i-fix-r-command-not-found-errors-running-bash-scripts-in-wsl).

That all makes sense, however is there a way/setting on Visual Studio Code on windows to not have to use the dos2unix utility every time?

Comment: See [Create portable, custom editor settings with EditorConfig](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options#supported-settings) - in particular the `end_of_line` property

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> In the bottom-right corner of the window there is an indicator that
>   says `CRLF` or `LF` [*highlighted in green on the picture*] which will let you set the line endings for a
>   particular file. Clicking on the text will allow you to change the
>   line endings as well.
>
> [image]

> `CR` is a bytecode for carriage return (from the days of typewriters) and `LF` similarly, for line feed. It just refers to the bytes that are placed as end-of-line markers.

Sources and references:

- [Visual Studio Code: How to show line endings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39532890/6543935).
- [VSC on GitHub: How to replace characters as newline break](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13459).
- [Difference between CR LF, LF and CR line break types?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1552770/6543935)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I also appreciate you posting the sources, it was educational and makes sense.