GitHub line ending issue in windows and linux
I have project on my windows running through wsl2, when i pushed the code to github and then clone that project on linux for deployment it shows all the file in modified stage.
how can handle this situation?

This question is similar to: How do I fix "$'\r': command not found" errors running Bash scripts in WSL?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See https://askubuntu.com/a/969966/158442 (clone using git installed in WSL, not git installed in Windows), or https://askubuntu.com/a/1277138/158442 (change your Windows editor line-ending config), or https://askubuntu.com/a/1260296/158442 (configure git's line-ending config)

AFAIK git always converts to LF internally - if you want to ensure line endings in files you checkout are correct for Windows you can configure that globally or per repository. See for example Configuring Git to handle line endings.

Very few traces of the actual problem here...
My guess:
line feeds in the files are Windowzy CR+LF
Linux uses LF only.
WSL: unknown entity in this regard.
Recommendation: Set your Windows or WSL file editor to use LF-only.
"Fix", on Ubuntu: Install and use dos2unix
$ sudo apt install dos2unix
for every file to be used on Linux, run dos2unix
e.g. find -exec dos2unix

still i have files when i enter git status
no file has been removed
