# No such file or directory when changing directory: Running shell script in ubuntu in windows 10

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been having issues changing directories using a shell script in windows 10.

In notepad I created a file, test.sh, which has the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd '/mnt/p/WMScriptTest/'
```

I then mounted the Ubuntu terminal to the location of the test.sh file by typing in `cd /mnt/p/` which works. Next, I typed in `./test.sh` and keep getting the following error message:

```
: No such file or directory/p/WMScriptTest/
```

I am new to using ubuntu and any help/suggestions are greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Please [edit] and add the output of `ls -l /mnt/p`. In a script one normally doesn’t use `cd`, but rather absolute paths. You can store paths in variables if that makes it easier, e.g. `mypath=/mnt/p/WMScriptTest` and then `mkdir "$mypath/mydir"` and `cp "$mypath/file1" "$mypath/mydir"`.

Comment: I just seem to be unable to change directories from code in my shell script. One of the folders listed from ls -l /mnt/p/  is WMScriptTest that I am trying to change directories to. If I change directories within the terminal itself it works though.

Comment: Is the error message really (literally) `: No such file or directory/p/WMScriptTest/`? That looks mangled somehow…

Comment: Yes, that is the exact message that I get

Comment: Maybe a problem with line endings? https://askubuntu.com/q/803162/507051

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. That may be what the issue is. However, when I try to get dos2unix by typing "sudo apt-get install dos2unix" I get a message that it is "unable to locate package dos2unix"

Comment: I’m clueless when it comes to repositories in WSL – try the `sed` approach maybe? ;P Oh, does it work in the command line directly btw?  Please try `bash -c "cd '/mnt/p/WMScriptTest/' && pwd"`, this should print “/mnt/p/WMScriptTest”.

Comment: Yes, that does print "/mnt/p/WMScriptTest" Also I was able to install dos2unix and used it on the file, but now when I run it in the terminal it gives no message at all and the directory remains unchanged.

Comment: So it works, great! :) A script runs in a subshell, it can’t change the directory of the shell it’s started from. If you want to test your script, add a line with `pwd` after the `cd` line. If you actually want to do something completely different, please [edit] your question and change it accordingly.

Comment: You’re welcome! Did you manage to solve the problem? If so, please add an answer below.

Comment: Yes everything is solved now!

Comment: Please add an answer below explaining the solution and possible misunderstandings so that it can help others as well.