# Error `Archive not supported` while opening extracted .js file in 18.04

Tags: files, filemanager, archive, unzip

I am getting [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpKUo.png) from Archive Manager when trying to open a text file:

> Could not open “users.js”
>   Archive type not supported.

I've tried different archive managers but not one works!

List of application I have in my machine to extract:

1. Archive Mounter
2. Xarchier (just downloaded but not working)
3. Archive Manager (default one)

This is the output of `file users.js` -> `users.js: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators`

Comment: Just from preference or is there a practical reason for doing so?

Comment: @Graham after doing extract zip folder.... when I clicking to open files it showing  `could not open users.js Archive not supported`

Comment: @Melebius I just edit my question please remove that duplicate link thanks melebius

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Generally a `.js` file should be a [text file containing JavaScript code](https://fileinfo.com/extension/js) rather than an archive. Could you add the output of the command `file users.js` to your question? (You’ll need to fill its correct path; you can also drag the file into the terminal window to fill the path automatically.) You could also open it in a text editor (like Gedit) and check if it is readable.

Comment: @Melebius I just edit my question and paste the output of user.js file.  It is readable in for text-edit software like sublime

Comment: @Melebius but in 16.04 I never get such error. even .js also opens smoothly in achieve manager

Comment: What does archive manager in 16.04 do with a `.js` file? My Xubuntu 16.04 opens a text editor (Mousepad) when I double-click a `.js` file.

Comment: In 16.04 without extracting .zip I can open any file in text editor. I also do double click and its open !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

Comment: @waltinator please read my question first then say it is duplicate... I already edit my question some days ago

Comment: CRLF line terminators? Windows line endings! See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803162/how-to-change-windows-line-ending-to-unix-version) for example.

Answer (score 1):

Archive manager programs are not designed to open plain text files.

It seems there is a bug somewhere with file associations that I've also encountered in Ubuntu 20.04 where the system defaults to opening .js files with archive-manager