# sha256sum: 'filename': No such file or directory

Tags: sha256, sha256sum

The command `sha256sum` correctly calculates checksum indicated in .sha256 file:

```
user@myHostname:~/Desktop/RT_N16/Merlin_JohnsFork$ sha256sum RT-N16_3.0.0.4_374.43_2-39L3j9527.trx
545927719c46e359a0db6bf9dcb348f99c0f3d8786725780cb182994c61b19be  RT-N16_3.0.0.4_374.43_2-39L3j9527.trx
```

All files are in the same directory.  I did **NOT** create the Contents of a .sha256 file:

```
user@myHostname:~/Desktop/RT_N16/Merlin_JohnsFork$ cat sha256sum.sha256 
545927719c46e359a0db6bf9dcb348f99c0f3d8786725780cb182994c61b19be  RT-N16_3.0.0.4_374.43_2-39L3j9527.trx
```

The `sha256sum` command reads the .sha256 file and returns an error:

```
user@myHostname:~/Desktop/RT_N16/Merlin_JohnsFork$ sha256sum -c sha256sum.sha256
sha256sum: 'RT-N16_3.0.0.4_374.43_2-39L3j9527.trx'$'\r': No such file or directory
: FAILED open or read_2-39L3j9527.trx
sha256sum: WARNING: 1 listed file could not be read
```

## QUESTIONS

- **Is the above syntax incorrect or is there a problem with the .sha256 file?**
- **Is the command trying to open a filename= `_2-39L3j9527.trx`?**

Comment: It seems the file name inside sha256sum.sha256 isn't present from where you're trying to sha256sum check. Either "RT-N16_3.0.0.4_374.43_2-39L3j9527.trx" should be present inside the same directory as sha256sum.sha256 or have its path specified in sha256sum.sha256 like `545927719c46e359a0db6bf9dcb348f99c0f3d8786725780cb182994c61b19be  /home/user/RT-N16_3.0.0.4_374.43_2-39L3j9527.trx`

Comment: How did you create `sha256sum.sha256`? It seems there is a formatting problem `'RT-N16_3.0.0.4_374.43_2-39L3j9527.trx'$'\r':` vs. `RT-N16_3.0.0.4_374.43_2-39L3j9527.trx`. Try to edit or recreate the file with an editor on your Ubuntu system.

Comment: The file appears to have Windows (CRLF) line endings - see [How to change Windows line-ending to Unix version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803162/how-to-change-windows-line-ending-to-unix-version)

Comment: @steeldriver   If you care to add a formal answer, you will earn due credit.  The `dos2unix` command corrected the .sha256 file for UNIX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look carefully, you can see that the message is actually

```
filename$'\r': No such file or directory
```

The `$'\r'` is the shell's way of telling you that there is a carriage return (`\r`) character at the end of the string. This indicates that the `sha256sum.sha256` file has DOS- or Windows-style line endings (CRLF) in place of the Unix standard LF endings.

You can fix the file using one of the methods described in [How to change Windows line-ending to Unix version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803162/how-to-change-windows-line-ending-to-unix-version)

You can use the program `dos2unix`, which is specifically designed for this:

```
dos2unix file.txt
```

will replace all CR from all lines, in place operation.

To save the output in a different file:

```
dos2unix -n file.txt output.txt
```

You might need to install it first by:

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
```